# Why is the cylinder surface on $\Bbb R^3$ orientable?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, differential-geometry, manifolds

Why is the cylinder surface on $\Bbb R^3$ orientable? Please can someone explain me clearly?

Comment: Intuitively, the outward pointing normal vector at a point will always point out as the point moves around the cylinder.  That is, we can specify two different 'sides' of the cylinder.  The same cannot be said of the Mobius band.  If you want a more mathematical explanation, you could write down an atlas, and show that the Jacobians of the transition functions have positive determinants.

Comment: How do I define the jacobian matrix? @jared

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the cylinder, $C$, is given by the equation $x^2+y^2=1$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, we can give an atlas of $C$ by
$$\begin{array}{ccc}U_1=C\setminus\{x=-1\}&&U_2=C\setminus\{x=1\}\\\varphi_1:U_1\to (-\pi,\pi)\times\mathbb{R}&&\varphi_2:U_2\to (0,2\pi)\times\mathbb{R}\\(x,y,z)\mapsto(\theta,z)&& (x,y,z)\mapsto(\theta,z)\end{array}$$

where $\theta$ is the polar angle of the point $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$.  The transition functions are then given by:

$$\psi_{12}=\varphi_1\circ\varphi_2^{-1}:(0,\pi)\cup(\pi,2\pi)\times\mathbb{R}\to(-\pi,0)\cup(0,\pi)\times\mathbb{R}\\[.1in](\theta,z)\mapsto\begin{cases}(\theta,z)&0<\theta<\pi\\[.1in](\theta-2\pi,z)&\pi<\theta<2\pi\end{cases}\\[.4in]\psi_{21}=\varphi_2\circ\varphi_1^{-1}:(-\pi,0)\cup(0,\pi)\times\mathbb{R}\to(0,\pi)\cup(\pi,2\pi)\times\mathbb{R}\\[.1in](\theta,z)\mapsto\begin{cases}(\theta,z)&0<\theta<\pi\\[.1in](\theta+2\pi,z)&-\pi<\theta<0\end{cases}$$

At this point, it would be very helpful to draw some pictures of $U_1$, $U_2$, and the open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ to which they are homeomorphic.  This will help you visualize the transition functions.

Now, we want to find the Jacobian of the transition functions.  If we write $\psi_{12}=(f_1,f_2)$, then the Jacobian is defined as follows:

$$\operatorname{Jac}(\psi_{12})=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial\theta}&\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial z}\\\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial\theta}&\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial z}\end{pmatrix}$$

Looking at how we defined $\psi_{12}$, we see that

$$f_1(\theta,z)=\begin{cases}\theta&0<\theta<\pi\\\theta-2\pi&\pi<\theta<2\pi\end{cases}$$

and $f_2(\theta,z)=z$.  Taking partial derivatives of these functions gives the Jacobian

$$\operatorname{Jac}(\psi_{12})=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial\theta}&\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial z}\\\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial\theta}&\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial z}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

You can also show this is the case for $\psi_{21}$.

Comment: Jared I haveunderstand but I what is these two jacobian matrix? Please can you write these two jacobian matrix clearly? And then I Will calculate the determinants of these two jacobian matrices, which show that C is orientable. But I need these two jacobian expression

Comment: By the way you explained very well:))

Comment: @B11: I've been more explicit.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes:))) of course:))) thank you so much for help:)

Comment: I have a question that how we can write transition function like that.I could not image in my mind.can you draw a picture please @Jared